# Issue Middleware Layer not Working in DOTNET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm using a custom middleware in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application.

I have this `program.cs` file:

```
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

if (_IsLicensingenabled)
{
    app.UseLicensingMiddleware();
}
```

And the code into the middleware layer is as below.

```
using F1_License_Library.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FulcrumOne_FileuploadBlobstorage_Service.Extensions
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class LicensingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private readonly CosmosConnector _cosmosConnector;
        private int Counter;

        public LicensingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration, CosmosConnector cosmosConnector)
        {
            _next = next;
            Configuration = configuration;
            _cosmosConnector = cosmosConnector;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            LicenseValidation lc = new LicenseValidation(Configuration, _cosmosConnector);
            bool Licensestatus = await lc.CheckLicenseandValidity();

            if (Licensestatus)
            {
                appLifetime.StopApplication();

                appLifetime.StopApplication();
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class LicensingMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseLicensingMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<LicensingMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

Never ever the code into the Invoke method is being get called.

The `Invoke` method does not run anytime.

Comment: Search following page for "HTTPS" (secure).  You server may require the secure mode : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0